# appending child node gives doctype error

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to debug why a clients site gives an error when browsed from mobile devices.

The following code which is called from javascript:

```
var dom = document.body; 
var jsel = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
jsel.language = 'php';
jsel.src = "test.php";
dom.appendChild(jsel);
```

Gives the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

That error occurs on the following line of code, the doc type of the web page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.2//EN" "http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/xhtml-mobile12.dtd">
```

If I replace the code to append javascript for example an alert box then it fires, however whenever including a php file, regardless of the file, it throws this error.  This same code executes fine on a standard web browser from a pc but only on mobile devices does it give this error.  Please help, changing the doctype to just show  doesn't make the error go away.  It seems to be including php files via the appendChild javascript call is giving the issue.

Been sitting on this issue for over 6 hours now, some help would be appreciated.

EDIT:  Thanks for responses, so basically the mobile webpage is supposed to allow uploading a file, once the user selects the file and clicks on the upload button it calls this javascript file which does various UI things such as displaying upload in progress text...that same file also embeds this PHP code that does the various functions to store to the Database.  The reason the javascript file and PHP file are being called this way is because there are multiple different pages in the site that use this same uploading code.

The site originally worked because only desktop users were targeted but now they needed this working on mobile devices as well and this is the issue we are hitting on mobile devices.

So the page is a smarty php template page with a button like this:

```
<input type="button" class="mainbutton" id="upload_button" name="upload_button" value="{$up_btnupload}" onClick="myFunction();">
```

myFunction() is sitting in an external JS file which calls the 'appendChild' code in order to execute the php code without doing a postback, it seems like a workaround they took to do the uploading code without posting back on the frontend.

Comment: Could you please post your full HTML document?

Comment: What does including a PHP file as a `<script>` supposed to do?

Comment: You should remove that `jsel.language = 'php';`, because the client (browser) does not care, as it cannot execute PHP. Is the PHP page supposed to return some JS code?

Comment: @Pointy: In the past you could prefix PHP code on your server with `<script language='php'>` instead of `<?php`

I'm pretty sure that has been deprecated and removed, though.

Comment: @WhoIsJohnDoe OK but that's not what's going on here - the code in this question is JavaScript and it's modifying the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for comments so far, see my edit in my original post.  The javascript that is modifying the DOM is trying to add the PHP file in a script tag, the fact that its a php file is giving the error, including JS files this way does not give issues.  It is necessary to execute the PHP file that is being added to the DOM for the upload functionality to store the file to the DB.

Again just to mention, this all works fine on desktop browsers, mobile devices however give that error and chrome's developer tools show the error happening on the doctype declaration.

Comment: Adding a PHP file URL as the "src" attribute of a `<script>` tag will cause the PHP file to run **on the server**, and the output will be what the browser sees. Since you're not setting the "type" attribute, the browser will interpret the server response as JavaScript.

Comment: setting the type attribute to php does nothing, it runs past the code but doesn't seem to execute it.

Comment: Is there perhaps a better way of embedding the php code via javascript into the page when the user clicks a button?